# Use async login function in react context

Tags: reactjs, async-await, axios

I have a problem with my React app. The fact is that I'm trying to implement a login system using local storage and context. The action for login is presented below:

```
const login = async (username, password) => {
    const user = await axios.post("http://localhost:4999/login", {username, password})
    dispatch({type: 'LOGIN', payload: user.data})
}
```

I use it inside my Main component, which contains a login form. The function called here is:

```
const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    await login(email, password)
}
```

The problem is that I receive an error that says:

> Unexpected reserved word 'await'

Can you tell me, please, what's the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also the onSubmit function must be async

```
 const onSubmit = async  (e) => {
     e.preventDefault()
     await login(email, password) }
```

Comment: Yes, you're right! But, I have another problem, if you can help me. Please... It's about the fact that localStorage variable named by me "user", which contains the user data for login don't remain the same if I refresh the page. I press the login button, user variable from localStorage is completed and after I refresh it becomes undefined. Do you know why?

Comment: The code you write Is not enough to give you an answer. I suppose that you have a reducer for the login action in wich you save your user. Maybe you dispatch another login action without payload. In that case you can avoid to dispatch an action with an empty payload or you can check the null/undefined payload in the reducer before save in localstorage